# How to create a regex that match only number and decimal separator in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to have a regex that reject string that contain any
alphabets. But allow numbers like: 4, 4.5, 12.330  but not 12.2.3.4 (multiple dots).

But why this regex of mine failed?

```
my $str1 = $ARGV[0] || "foo1";


if ($str1 =~ /^[\d+]|[^a-zA-Z]+|[\.]\d+$/) {
  print "This is strictly numeric: $str1\n";
}
else {
   print "This contain alphabet\n";
}
```

The input still pass first condition which I don't want.

Running example here:https://eval.in/73654

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($str1 =~ /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/) { ... }
```

If you want to allow also strings that ends with decimal separator with no followed digits, the go with

```
if ($str1 =~ /^\d+(?:\.\d*)?$/) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need parens around your ors:

```
if ( $str1 =~ /^([\d+]|[^a-zA-Z]+|[\.]\d+)$/ ) {
```

also

`[^a-zA-Z]+` will match everything that `\d+` or `\.\d+` would.

also

you could write the first and last terms as simply `\.?\d+`

but really, that's not what you want since you also want 4.5 which would match against something like `\d+\.?\d*`

Comment: Thanks how can I make it such that it match 3.5 but not 3.4.5, i.e we have to strict the number to contain one digit separator but not more.

Comment: Use the last pattern in my updated answer.  `[^a-zA-Z]+` will match too much.